# How do I restart computer using C# on EC2 Ubuntu Server?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, amazon-ec2

I am running a C# Console Application on AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu. I want to restart the computer from my Application using C#. Is there is any way that I can execute `sudo reboot` from C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same way you would do it on any other machine. Look at the Process class from System.Diagnostics. For starters, read here: http://www.csharp-station.com/howto/processstart.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works using the below code.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "/usr/bin/sudo";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/sbin/shutdown -r now";
process.Start();
```